# Angular11 - Spring Boot - MySQL: POST request not successfully creating database entry

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot

### Background

I am attempting to build a ticketing system CRUD app using Angular11, Spring Boot, and MySQL.

The database tables are being created successfully. I am able to view test data and create that is manually with MySQL or with Postman.

**My problem is when I try to use a simple form to create a Ticket entry in the database, the entry is not successfully created.**

I am not getting any error messages at all.

### My Code

#### Front End

ticket.ts

```
export class Ticket {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  createdOn?: number;
  resolutionDate?: number;

  constructor(title: string, description: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

ticket.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Ticket } from '../models/Ticket';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TicketService {
  apiServerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/tickets';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTickets(): Observable<Ticket[]> {
    return this.http.get<Ticket[]>(this.apiServerUrl);
  }

  get(id: number): Observable<Ticket> {
    return this.http.get<Ticket>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  create(ticket: Ticket) {
    const url = `${this.apiServerUrl}/create`;

    console.log(url, ticket);
    return this.http.post<Ticket>(url, ticket);
  }
}
```

create-ticket.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Ticket } from 'src/app/models/Ticket';
import { TicketService } from '../../../services/ticket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'create-ticket',
  templateUrl: './create-ticket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-ticket.component.css'],
})
export class CreateTicketComponent implements OnInit {
  ticketForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    description: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  constructor(
    private ticketService: TicketService,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let title = new FormControl();
    let description = new FormControl();

    this.ticketForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  public createTicket() {
    const newTicket = new Ticket(
      this.ticketForm.value.title,
      this.ticketForm.value.description
    );

    this.ticketService.create(newTicket);
    this.router.navigate(['/tickets']);
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/tickets']);
  }
}
```

#### Back End

TicketController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tickets")
public class TicketController {

    @Autowired
    private TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    ...
    @PostMapping("/create")
        public ResponseEntity<Ticket> createTicket(@RequestBody Ticket ticket) {
            try {
                Ticket _ticket = ticketRepository.save(ticket);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(_ticket, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
```

### What I've tried

If I use Postman and send a POST request with JSON, this successfully creates a database entry.
[image: postman example of successful entry]

In **ticket.service.ts**, `return this.http.post<Ticket>(url, ticket);`
The output from `console.log(url, ticket)` is:
[image: log output]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue is that my CreateTicketComponent was not subscribing properly to the changes in my form.

The new CreateTicketComponent is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Ticket } from 'src/app/models/Ticket';
import { TicketService } from '../../../services/ticket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'create-ticket',
  templateUrl: './create-ticket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-ticket.component.css'],
})
export class CreateTicketComponent implements OnInit {
  ticketForm: FormGroup;
  ticket: Ticket;

  constructor(
    private ticketService: TicketService,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.ticketForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.ticket = new Ticket(
      this.ticketForm.value.title,
      this.ticketForm.value.description
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onValueChanges();
  }

  onValueChanges(): void {
    this.ticketForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.ticket = val;
    });
  }

  public createTicket() {
    this.ticketService
      .create(this.ticket)
      .subscribe((result) => this.goToTicketList());
  }

  goToTicketList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/tickets']);
  }
}
```